# How to block initializing state of Child when Parent component loads in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have `SideBar` Component.

And this SideBar has state hooks.

```
const [selectRegion, setSelectRegion] = useState("");
```

This selectRegion value is set "" as initialized value.

And when it's rendered, this value is updated as getting from `Firebase`.

```
const auth = getAuth();
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
    if (user) {
      currentUserId = user.uid;

      const userDocRef = doc(firebaseDB, "admin", currentUserId);
      const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef);
      if (userDocSnap.exists()) {
        const userDBRegion = userDocSnap.data().region;
        const userDBSmallRegion = userDocSnap.data().smallRegion;
        const userDBFullRegion = `${userDBRegion} ${userDBSmallRegion}`;
        setSelectRegion(userDBFullRegion);

        const userDBMaster = userDocSnap.data().master;
        setUserMaster(userDBMaster);
      }
    }
   });
```

This selectRegion value is shown on SideBar.

And This SideBar component is part of all Screen.

For example, `User` screen has SideBar as Child.

```
 <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "start",
        position: "relative",
        flex: 1,
      }}
    >
      <SideBar changeRegion={changeRegion} />
...
```

So If I move from `User` screen to another Screen, even if `selectRegion` value is same, SideBar component is re-rendered and it's initialized as `""`, then this value is updated.

And this makes this value is blinking whenever I move screen from to somewhere.

I don't want value blinking from "" to real value if value is same.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`memo`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo) for the sidebar component to not re-render when the parent component re-renders. Using `memo`, the `sidebar` will only re-render if the component props are not the same.

```
const Sidebar = React.memo(function Sidebar(props) {
   // return ...
});
```

If it still keeps re-rendering, you'll probably need to cache the `changeRegion` function using `useCallback` that way the function you're passing to the sidebar will always be the same.

```
const cachedChangeSelection = useCallback(() => {
  // changeSelection Implementation
}, [YOUR_DEPENDENCIES]);

const Sidebar = React.memo(function Sidebar(props) {
       // return ...
});
```

Note: even though we're using `memo`, the `Sidebar` component will re-render if it is inside a context and the value for that context changes.